# Cauchy-Binet formula for squares

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics

Using the convention of the wikipedia article, Cauchy-Binet formula states that --for $A, \, n\times m$ and $B, \, m\times n$ matrices--

$$ 
\det(AB) = \sum_{S\in\tbinom{[n]}m} \det(A_{[m],S})\det(B_{S,[m]})
$$

My question is, is there a formula for the "squares" i.e.

$$ 
\sum_{S\in\tbinom{[n]}m} \det(A_{[m],S})^2 \det(B_{S,[m]})^2 = ?
$$

Many thanks